# How can we sync the payments from google checkout on website and android app?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-checkout

In my android app I have in app products which a user could buy using IAB 3 . And these products are available on website also. I want to know if there is a way that these two payments may be synced together. How would this be possible .Please help?